# How do I install OSSIM (Alientvault SIEM) manually?

Tags: linux, security, ubuntu-12.04

AlienVault by defult is a .iso image. It installed on the core of Debian. I want to install it on Ubuntu 12.04. How can i do that?! Or is it possible or not?! (AlienVault is a SIEM product, it is an open source monitoring security logs .., and use in Security Operations Center. Due to some reasons i need to installing it on Ubuntu. All the files of this product are in pool directory of its Debian .iso image.

Answer (score 1):

Do **not** attempt this. Alienvault has made modifications on a number of core packages which can easily destroy a standard install.

As a longtime Alienvault user I can say the vast majority ight the time it doesn't matter what the underlying OS is.  I'm mostly a red hat and centos guy myself and I rarely need to get cli access. When I do it's less than 1 in 100 that I need to use distro specific commands or settings.

Almost everything is controlled from the alienvault config file directory.